# Linux command to disconnect machine

Tags: linux, command, iptables, disconnect

Sometimes we require to test the scenario if some machine goes out of network. i.e. to drop the communication between two machines.
Linux provides a way to simulate such a situation. Whats the command for the same?

---

The one command i know is

```
iptables -I INPUT -s IP_ADRRESS -j DROP
```

To Take that one back in network

```
iptables -I INPUT -s IP_ADRRESS -j ACCEPT
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about shutdown the interface? `ifdown eth0` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to complement Aryan answer, if you are on the testing machine and want to simulate that the remote machine at IP address IP_REMOTE becomes unreachable

`iptables -I OUTPUT -d IP_REMOTE -j DROP`

to restore

`iptables -D OUTPUT -d IP_REMOTE -j DROP`